# What does ?DataType mean in Vb.NET

Tags: vb.net, nullable

I have the following line of code:

```
CType(IIf(CBool(product.IsDiscontinued Is Nothing Or product.IsDiscontinued = True), False, True), Boolean?)
```

What does the `Boolean?` mean at the end. I have seen it used on other data types as well.

Comment: (as a note, the [tag:nullable] was added by me. It was already used by more than 400 questions. The OP clearly didn't know it was nullable. I've removed the [tag:vb] tag because the code is clearly vb.net)

Comment: @xanatos You should put comments like that in the **Edit Summary** field. That's what it's there for!

Comment: @dlev But I forgot to do it :-(, and I had to repair before someone pointed out "hey but he did know about nullable"

Comment: @xanatos Fair enough. Wasn't sure if you knew about the field or not. :)

Answer (score 5):

That's a [`Nullable(Of Boolean)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

It allows value types to be `Nothing`.

Comment: +1, Nitpick: Value types can already be `Nothing` in VB.Net.  `Nothing` is treated as the equivalent of `default(T)`.

Comment: Yes; I actually knew that.  However, `null` isn't VB, so there's not much else to say.

Answer (score 5):

The `?` at the end is a shortcut for `Nullable<T>`, in this case `Nullable<Boolean>`.

Using Nullable allows you to store null inside of a value type that you wouldn't otherwise be able to.

Answer (score 2):

Nullable... It's a nullable boolean...

As a quick aside, in the back end, these can create boxing/unboxing fun if you're not careful...

Here's a nice article explaining it (though it's written for c#)

http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2008/04/26/c-and-nullable-value-types.aspx

Comment: Yup, you're right... I caught myself and corrected... sorry for the misprint!

Comment: `these can create boxing/unboxing fun if you're not careful` How should they create boxing/unboxing more easily than their base type?

Comment: I was referring to the fact that the clr has specific code designed for boxing/unboxing nullables... Not that they were necessarily easier to box... This is from Richter: "Specifcally, when the CLR is boxing a Nullable<T> instance, it checks to see if it is null, and 
if so, the CLR doesn’t actually box anything, and null is returned  If the nullable instance is 
not null, the CLR takes the value out of the nullable instance and boxes it  In other words, 
a Nullable<Int32> with a value of 5 is boxed into a boxed-Int32 with a value of 5"... I was merely making an aside that boxing was different

Comment: Ah ok :-) Now it's clearer! :-) :-) But then why "If you are not careful"? It seems more a warning: if you do something wrong, you'll cause boxing.